# How can I implement a jQuery load callback function differently for .success and .fail?

Tags: jquery

I have read the jQuery API but I am still unclear. Here's an example of code that I have:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            type: 'GET'
        })
        .success(function (content) {
            $('#content')
                .html("<div class='block-border'>" + content + "</div>")
                .applyTemplateSetup()
                .buildTableOfContent();
            if ($('#cityLegend-1').length) {
                $('#cityLegend-1').html("Question " + html);
            }
            $('#article').css('visibility', 'visible');
            var editHref = "/Admin/Contents/Edit?pk=0003000&rk=" + href.substring(2,5);
            $('#editContent').attr('data-href', editHref);
        })
        .fail(function (ajaxContext) {
            ajaxOnFailure(ajaxContext)
        });
```

I **must** use jQuery .load for this as my template is already coded to do some effect and call jQuery .load(). But how can I make my callback do things differently as I have here with the functions that get executed if there is a .success or a .fail and how could I implement a .done function.

One more question. If I am able to use .load then will it be a problem if my content contains HTML mark up. This is very likely and I read in some places that this might be a problem.

Comment: The way it is at the moment, using `$.ajax`, it is fine. I'd say keep it as is, you can never go wrong using `$.ajax`. The second question you can look it up, that's mostly browser dependent and involves mostly `<head/>` and `<script/>` tags

Comment: "Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8."  To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead."

Answer (score 4):

Like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  },
  error: function(data){
    //error
  },
 complete: function(data){
   //complete
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I do this using jQuery .load ?  I have some wrapper code that calls jQuery .load so I need to convert the above.

Answer (score 1):

This may be of help.

```
$("#content").load(href, function(response, status, xhr){
  if(status == "error") {
    ajaxOnFailure(response);
  } else {
    ajaxOnSuccess(response);
  }
});
```

(By the way, there is an example in [`.load()`'s documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for error handling

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#races a').click(function () {
  $('#results').load('Racing/' + $(this).attr('href') + ' #wrap', "", function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
   switch (XMLHttpRequest.status) {
    case 200: break;
    case 404:
     $('#results').html('<p>Looks like the results have not been uploaded to the server yet. Please check back later.</p>');
     break;
    default:
     $('#results').html('<p>' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ': ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText + '. Please contact the club and let them know.</p>');
     break;
   }
  });
  return false;
 });
});
```